# Why std::function has no function_type or equivalent member type?

Tags: c++, c++11, std-function

From [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) it seems to me that the `std::function` has no `function_type` or equivalent member type to export the actual type used to initialize it.
It has `result_type`, `argument_type`, as well as `first_argument_type` and `second_argument_type`, but nothing like the type above mentioned.
Why it doesn't offer such a type as part of its interface?
There will be for sure a good reason for that, but I can't figure out what's that reason, so I'm just curious to find it out.

---

For I know the first question will be *why do you need it*, well, imagine that I want to do something like `std::is_same<F1::function_type, F2::function_type>::value` to check if their underlying types are the same in a sfinae evaluation, where it's fine if they contain different functions as long as the signs are the same.
<sub>I admit that it doesn't make much sense, to be honest the question is just for the sake of curiosity.</sub>

**EDIT**

As noted by @Brian in the comments of [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36509248/4987285), I misused the term *initialize* when I wrote:

> to export the actual type used to initialize it

What I'm interested in is the template argument indeed.
As an example, for a `std::function<void(S&, int)>` (where `S` is a struct), `function_type` would be `void(S&, int)`.

Comment: For the `is_same` check, you can simply check if `F1` and `F2` are the same type, can't you?

Comment: @Brian yeah, absolutely, note my comment *I admit that it doesn't make much sense*!! :-) ... I'm just curious to know if there is a reason for which it is not part of the interface of the function, even if I can't find a reasonable use for it and this would be already a good response indeed. I'm not sure if *it's useless* is the only reasonable response or if there are some other reasons. That's all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you're asking the wrong question. The right question is: why should there be such a member type?

If, say, you write a function template that can accept any specialization of `std::function`, then the template parameter will already be immediately available to you:

```
template <typename T>
void f(std::function<T> F) {
    // you wouldn't write decltype(F)::function_type here; you'd just write T
}
```

The more inconvenient case is the one in which you have some function like

```
template <typename Callable>
void f(Callable C);
```

Here, you have no guarantee that `Callable` is a `std::function` specialization, so even if `std::function<T>` had `typedef T function_type`, you wouldn't want to access `Callable::function_type` for an arbitrary callable. So it wouldn't be of any use here.

The right question is: why do some standard library classes expose their template parameters, for example, containers of `T` (which have `typedef T value_type`)? The answer is that the standard has a specific set of requirements that the container types have to satisfy, which reflects a design goal that it should be possible to write generic algorithms that work on different types of containers, not all of which would be template specializations of the form `C<T>`. It then makes sense to mandate that all containers expose `value_type` because that's the only uniform way of extracting the element type from arbitrary containers.

If `std::function` were also an instance of some `Callable` concept, it would make sense to have the requirement that there is a `function_type` typedef so that code accepting any `Callable` could access the function type. But that's not the case, and it's not useful to have it for only the single template `std::function`.

Answer (score 3):

You can easily write one:

```
template < typename T >
struct function_type;

template < typename Sig >
struct function_type<std::function<Sig>> { using type = Sig; };
```

On your terminology: *instantiate* is the word you're looking for.  You are looking for the type that the template was *instantiated* with.

The only people who know why it isn't a member type are those who designed the feature and those who voted it in (maybe).  It could simply be something nobody thought of.  It does seem a bit obvious, but that's in hindsight from the perspective of wanting it.